# regarding using lucene in other languages and tools

Tags: python, r, lucene, full-text-search, nlp

Is that possible to import Lucene index using R or Python? In terms of the text mining purposes, does Lucene index perform much better than traditional text feature construction approaches, e.g., bag-of-words?

Comment: For other languages, you could access the lucene database as a web service.

Comment: You can also use Jython, or PyLucene.